# Share Image to my Facebook page using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I need to share image an to my facebook page. I used the following code:

```
string accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCESSTOKEN"].ToString();
string pageId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PAGEID"].ToString();

string ImagePath = Server.MapPath("Images/img.jpg");

FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
fb.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPID"].ToString();
fb.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPSECRET"].ToString();

 var imgstream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);
 dynamic res = fb.Post(pageId + "/photos", new
 {
  message = "Test Message",
  file = new FacebookMediaStream
  {
    ContentType = "image/jpg",
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
   }.SetValue(imgstream)
   });
```

It worked and displayed in "Recent posts by other on [page name]" with my name. Im the admin of this page. For me It should display as posted by admin. help me guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

You can use  of stream publish method, Here is the sample demo url by using this method it is also possible to share video, flash and mp3 aslo

http://demo.vatlab.net/StreamPublish.aspx

http://sudiptasanyal.blogspot.in/2011/09/share-image-with-facebook-in-aspnet.html

Solution 2:

Use of Graph API , refer more about

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Share-Image-Photo-Pictures-on-Facebook-in-ASPNet-using-Graph-API.aspx

Comment: The image is successfully posted. my problem is, it displayed in Recent posts by other on [page name]. how to post image as admin?